# I don't know why cookie not working on mobile website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, httponly

I have a website that work well on desktop but on mobile not, the cookie is not set only on mobile and i don't know why. this is the cookie settings

```
const cookieSettings = {
  // one week
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  path: "/",
  sameSite: "none",
  secure: true,
  httpOnly: true,
};
```

I use Next JS and Express JS, host on vercel and heroku